# Could not load type 'BestPricingEngine.Main'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have searched through Stackoverflow, Google, and tried different configurations like CodeFile rather than CodeBehind.  The error changes slightly but still get it, really stuck on this one.  Any help will be appreciated.  The exact error is below, my code for that error is below that.

Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'BestPricingEngine.Main'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="Import FBA Orders" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/MasterPage.Master"  CodeBehind="ImportFBAOrders.cs" Inherits="BestPricingEngine.Main" %>
Line 2:  <%@ Register src="ImportFBAOrders.ascx" tagname="ImportFBAOrders" tagprefix="ucImportFBAOrders"%>
Line 3:

Source File: /Pages/ImportFBAOrders/ImportFBAOrders.aspx    Line: 1

```
<%@ Page Title="Import FBA Orders" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/MasterPage.Master"  CodeBehind="ImportFBAOrders.cs" Inherits="BestPricingEngine.Main" %>
<%@ Register src="ImportFBAOrders.ascx" tagname="ImportFBAOrders" tagprefix="ucImportFBAOrders"%>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="server"></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpSidebar" Runat="server">


</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpMainContent" runat="server">
<ucImportFBAOrders:ImportFBAOrders ID="importFBAOrders" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

[image: ImportFBAOrders.cs]

Comment: What is BestPricingEngine.Main? If it is a class library then should it not be BestPricingEngine.cs? I don't recognize that file extension.

Comment: BestPricingEngine is the namespace, the Main is Main.aspx.  I don't understand why it is trying to load Main there

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. Did you try referencing the namespace with an `Imports`, `Using`, or `Inherits` in the code behind? If so, did you get the same error there? I'm just curious to see if it can find the namespace. Did you add the inherits attribute manually?

Comment: CodeBehind="ImportFBAOrders.cs" Inherits="BestPricingEngine.Main" %>

Comment: I have that in the code.  I remove .Main and get the error that BestPricingEngine could not be loaded

Answer (score 1):

There should not be a period in your BestPricingEngine.Main. The `Inherits` attribute is normally used in the markup to reference the code-behind of that page.

In other words, looking at this code, I would assume your `Inherits` attribute should be named after that page's class, which is usually the path of the code-behind file delimited by underscores, and excluding the file extension.

### EDIT

Change `Inherits="BestPricingEngine.Main"` to `Inherits="BestPricingEngine.Pages"`

Comment: Not sure how it happened.  I pulled a dll and decompiled it in ILSpy and got the source code for the project, as there was none to be found.  Everything compiles fine and the site loads and does all the good stuff, but when I click the link ImportFBAOrders, I then get this error.  I just added existing files to the project after the decompilization.

Comment: @webby68 when you look at the `.cs` file that is the code-behind of the page that is giving you the error, what is the name of the class? In vb.net it will look like `Partial Class ImportFBAOrders`

Comment: public class ImportFBAOrders : UserControl

Comment: If I could send you a screenhshot I would show you, that is in the ImportFBAOrders.cs

Comment: I just loaded the image

Comment: I changed the Inherits to Inherits="ImportFBAOrders" and got a similar error > Could not load type 'ImportFBAOrders'.

Comment: Sorry, don't seem to be so blonde, this is newer learning for me, maybe I am missing what you intended to get across

Comment: Got the following error: Could not load type 'BestPricingEngine.Pages'.

Comment: @webby68 Not something I normally see, but it looks like you have a user control (*ascx* file) and a webpage (*aspx* file) that share the same name. Can you make sure that the image you loaded is of the code-file that is attached to your `.aspx` page and not the `.ascx` control?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42062/discussion-between-lopsided-and-webby68)